# Is a WinJS/Javascript + Html5 app written for Windows 8 compatible with Windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Is a WinJS/Javascript + Html5 app written in javascript for Windows 8 compatible with Windows phone 8? From today's presentation, the recommended way is C#/XAML. It makes me wonder if my js app for windows 8 becomes compatible with WP8 (ofcourse with minor changes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information released at the [June 2012 Windows Phone Summit](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows-Phone/Summit), it appears that the development choices for Windows Phone 8 are:

> - XAML with C#/VB code
> - Native C++/C code
> - HTML 5 Browser Control

Based on their choice of wording, I infer that both C++/XAML and WinRT/HTML5 development models will not be available.

We'll know more once a preview of the WP8 SDK is released "later this summer".

Answer (score 0):

> WinJS/Javascript + Html5 app written in javascript for Windows 8 compatible with Windows phone 8?

No. Apps (not games) are still written in C#/VB.NET and XAML.

If your app runs in the browser, IE10 is able to render HTML5, but you'll not get any platform interop features.